# How can I implement my own custom MFMailComposeView?

Tags: iphone, ios, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I've been playing around with a lot of apps recently and one that has caught my attention is boxes. They've somehow managed to implement their own custom MFMailComposeView.

As you can see below, they've implemented their own custom brown header bar and in the body section; added meta data about the app version, ios version and the phone with greyed out text. How can I go about doing this?

[image]

Comment: Wow, this navigation bar must look really bad in some localizations when buttons stretch over those lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overly simple:

```
mailViewController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor purpleColor]; // whatever
[mailViewController setMessageBody:@"<hr /><p>Foo Bar</p>" isHTML:YES];
```

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing custom about this at all. The custom look to the navbar is probably an app wide setup using the `UIAppearance` proxy for `UINavigationBar`.

The text shown in the email message is simply a pre-populated message body using HTML to get the text color and the line.

All of this is done using standard APIs and the standard `MFMailComposeViewController`.

I do the same in my own app.

Answer (score 0):

You have to customise the Navigation bar thats point1

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:25.0f/255.0f green:60.0f/255.0f blue:106.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationbar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Next set your foooter you can acheive grey text by editing the text font  and stuff of footer

Note* The Code below is a rough idea

```
- (id)initWithSubject:(NSString *)subject body:(NSString *)body footer:(NSString *)footer{

  //do the instaitatiaon check for nil

self.mailComposeDelegate = self;

[self setSubject:subject];    

body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", body, footer];

[self setMessageBody:body isHTML:YES]; 

return self;
}
```

Hope this Helps You out.

Better you can Add html text where you can customise a lot :)

Comment: `[super init];` is not any good. First you have to assign `self` to its return value, second, you have to check it being `nil`.